# Why is my code stuck on executing message

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a code that will count the number of times data from a specific field is being repeated over time e.g

In data frame below, in the column labelled 'Test' i want to calculate the number of times that rows next to each other contains 'Residential' in the 'type' field. Written the expected value in red.
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En9ig.png)

So far i have written the code below, but it remains stuck on the executing message.

```
i=0
while i<= len(df):
    j=0
    k=i
    while df.iloc[k,7]=='Residential':
        j +=1
        df.at[k,15] =j
        k+1
    i+=1
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: `k+1` should be `k += 1` (which is quite baffling, because you increment other variables correctly twice in other parts of the cde.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All good, i manage to find the solution, Code was suck on while loop because of typo error

```
bit= False
exe= True
for i in range (len(df)):
    if df.iloc[i,7] != 'Residential':
        bit= False
    if bit and i != 0:
        df.iloc[i,14]= df.iloc[(i-1),14]

    if not bit and df.iloc[i,7]=='Residential':
        counter=0
        k= i
        while df.iloc[k,7]=='Residential' and exe:
            bit= True
            counter += 1
            df.iloc[i,14] = counter
            if k < (len(df)-1):
                k += 1
            else:
                exe= False
```